# getting pivot columns in collection in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

how to return collection of eloquent models with pivot column? For example, there are M:N relationship between users and vats. I want to retrieve all users data( with vats and with pivot column (costOfDelivery) , which is in pivot table user_vat).

In my code I have:

```
$vats = Vat::whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
     })->with('country')
            ->get();
```

but this return data from vats and country, not from pivot table "user_vat", how to retrieve also costOfDelivery?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from pivot table

Comment: I edited my answer, I only return json with data

Comment: Do you use ->withPivot('costOfDelivery'); in your relation method?

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the data from pivot table, you must use pivot attribute

Something like this

```
foreach($users->roles as $role){
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

To return json, you can use the `toJson()` method like

```
$vat->toJson();
```

Comment: i changed my post, please checked it... I need to return json with data, not write to output by echo...

Comment: thanks, this works. However, how to select only specified column from related table? For example when I want select name of country for related vat. I want do something like this : ..->select('rate', 'country.name') , where "rate" is in vat table and "name" from country. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/**
 * The model class with the belongsToMany user class relation.
 */
class Vat extends Model
{
    public function user() 
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(\App\User::class)
             ->withPivot(['cost_of_delivery', /**Specific columns for the pivot.*/]);  
    }

}
```

---

```
<?php

/*
 * Your query (which I think is a little bit complicated that it should be.
 */
$vats = Vat::whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
 })->with(['country', 'users'])
        ->get();
```

---

I would use sth. like:

```
<?php
$user->load(['vats.country']);
$vats = $user->getRelationValue('vats');
```

And

```
$vats->first()->pivot->cost_of_delivery
```

should give you the cost of delivery of the first vat.